# Rotating the Prize text 90 degree in Lottery Wheel script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use the [`lottery-wheel` package](https://fralonra.github.io/lottery-wheel/) to setup a lucky draw spinning wheel for a page. Everything is working well except that when I added more prizes into the wheel. The Prizes text in the wheel will overlap and hidden as each section gets smaller or when the name of the Prizes are long. Are there anyway the script could be rotated to 90 degree so that the first character of the Prizes text will be pointing towards the center?

I try to find the contact for the developer but failed, so hope someone in the community can help to point out to me which part of the js file script I should modify to make it work.

Below is the link to the Git
https://github.com/fralonra/lottery-wheel

Answer (score 0):

Please update the package to version over 2.5, and there is a new option call `textRotate` which supports this feature.